# How to connect Elektronika BK-0010 to an RS-232 interface?

Tags: rs232, electronika-bk

Does any one of you have an electronic diagram and description of connecting the RS-232 serial bus to the Lithuanian computer Elektronika BK-0010? I need a diagram of a device to make myself.

My computer is manufactured in Šiauliai, Lithuania, at the NUKLON plant (BK 0010-01 versions only).

Answer (score 2):

> Lithuanian computer ELEKTRONIKA BK 0010

Was there really a Lithuanian version?

The [BK-0010](https://web.archive.org/web/20070106194307/http://bk0010.narod.ru/) Monitor offers, as far as I know, a basic RS-232 type interface, please see [this (Russian) article](https://gid.pdp-11.ru/a/vtiep/1991/07/02.html) ([English version](https://gid-pdp--11-ru.translate.goog/a/vtiep/1991/07/02.html?_x_tr_sl=ru&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=de&_x_tr_pto=wapp)). It also describes a software based approach using the parallel interface. For use with a level converter see here

For a more modern hardware solution you may follow [this project](http://forum.pk-fpga.ru/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=5606).

Comment: "Was there really a Lithuanian version?", it's possible OP conflates the nationality of the computer with the fact it's OS, the Vilnius BASIC is from Lithuania

Comment: "For use with a level converter see here" it looks like you're missing a link. But also be careful, this is basically a link-only answer

Comment: @Lorraine I'd say it's quite average, beside, what else to tell than it's already build in. Also, you're always free to write a better one :))

Comment: Where is the link to the level convertor? It seems to be missing.

Comment: @Greenonline oops...now I need to find that again.

Comment: Although the basic RS-232 type interface used TTL voltage levels, 30+ years ago my BK-0010-01 worked with a modem without level converters quite reliably.

Comment: @LeoB. which only means it being tolerant of higher voltages - if used at all.